# Intellij IDEA 14 and Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat8

I'm newbie in web development with Java and try to run my first "Hello World" app on Intellij 14 + Tomcat 8.0. Every time I got error "404".

Tomcat without Intellij work perfectly on http://localhost:8080/ as Windows 7 service.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My index.xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
   <f:view>
      <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
   </f:view>
</html>
```

Configuration of Tomcat 8:

[Debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiWNX.jpg)

Catalina.log:

```
09-Nov-2015 08:11:12.741 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: Invalid command '' received
09-Nov-2015 08:11:15.890 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: Invalid command '' received
09-Nov-2015 08:11:24.473 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Nov-2015 08:11:24.674 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Nov-2015 08:11:24.725 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
09-Nov-2015 08:11:24.959 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Nov-2015 08:11:25.012 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.997 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.997 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.28.0
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.997 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.997 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.998 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.998 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.998 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_65-b17
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.998 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.999 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.999 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.999 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
09-Nov-2015 09:12:48.999 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
09-Nov-2015 09:12:49.000 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
09-Nov-2015 09:12:49.000 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\temp
09-Nov-2015 09:12:49.000 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
09-Nov-2015 09:12:49.000 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\logging.properties
09-Nov-2015 09:12:49.000 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
09-Nov-2015 09:12:49.000 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
09-Nov-2015 09:12:49.000 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
09-Nov-2015 09:12:49.001 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;;.
09-Nov-2015 09:12:50.595 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Nov-2015 09:12:51.071 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Nov-2015 09:12:51.073 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Nov-2015 09:12:51.076 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Nov-2015 09:12:51.076 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 4183 ms
09-Nov-2015 09:12:51.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
09-Nov-2015 09:12:51.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
09-Nov-2015 09:12:51.190 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs
09-Nov-2015 09:12:52.137 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [251] milliseconds.
09-Nov-2015 09:12:52.163 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs has finished in 973 ms
09-Nov-2015 09:12:52.163 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager
09-Nov-2015 09:12:52.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager has finished in 54 ms
09-Nov-2015 09:12:52.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT
09-Nov-2015 09:12:52.265 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT has finished in 48 ms
09-Nov-2015 09:12:52.272 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Nov-2015 09:12:52.282 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Nov-2015 09:12:52.285 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1209 ms
09-Nov-2015 09:15:07.235 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Nov-2015 09:15:07.247 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Nov-2015 09:15:07.298 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
09-Nov-2015 09:15:07.355 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Nov-2015 09:15:07.358 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.705 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.28.0
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_65-b17
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.708 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.709 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.710 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\temp
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.710 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.710 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\logging.properties
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.710 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.710 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.711 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.711 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;;.
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.884 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.972 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.974 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.977 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Nov-2015 10:08:14.977 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 725 ms
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.002 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.002 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.011 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.482 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [130] milliseconds.
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.500 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs has finished in 489 ms
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.500 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.579 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager has finished in 79 ms
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.579 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.609 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT has finished in 30 ms
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.621 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.632 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Nov-2015 10:08:15.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 656 ms
09-Nov-2015 10:08:33.224 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Nov-2015 10:08:33.227 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Nov-2015 10:08:33.278 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
09-Nov-2015 10:08:33.313 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Nov-2015 10:08:33.317 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: Show us `Deployment` tab.

Comment: Deployment tab http://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Pa3.jpg

Comment: Nice, it explains your issue

Answer (score 0):

According to your `Deployment` screenshot tab, you have to fix value of the field `Open browser` on tab `Server` to value `http://localhost:8080/JSFDemo` and use this path to work with your web-application run from IDEA.

Comment: Changed open browser field from http://localhost:8080 to http://localhost:8080/JSFDemo but still 404 error

Comment: And after start Tomcat from Intellij address http://localhost:8080/ does not work also 404 error

Comment: @mkoval , you should attach logs of tomcat to your question

Comment: Added catalina.log to question